# Replacing values with parts of strings from a label-list [R]

Tags: r

I'll try to word this as best as I can, bear with me.

I have raw data consisting of 200 columns. 
Values of each column have been assigned numbers which now need to be replaced with their underlying values.

For each column the underlying values change, making the task very tedious.

I have received a list of underlying values, but all underlying values of a column are listed in one cell. 
String could look something like ["1 = Very much 2 = Moderately 3 = Not so much"]
I have attached a picture to try to help you gain understanding.

[On the left is my raw data and on the right the labels I have received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unfey.png)

Since I have 200 columns of this nonsense, "search and replace" in Excel Spreadsheets would be hell on earth for this task. Therefore I'm looking for a way to utilise the rows of labels and automate it in R.

I only have a week of experience in R, so I'm unaware of the strengths and limitations of R to solve such a task.

Thanks for anyone reading my debut as a novelist, I would appreciate any help, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `forcats::fct_collapse` to each column in `df` using `sapply`

```
library(rlang) #for !!!
data.frame(sapply(names(df), 
                  function(x) forcats::fct_collapse(as.factor(df[[x]]), !!!lab[[x]])))

     Q1     Q2
1   Yes    All
2    NO   Some
3 Maybe Rarely
4 Maybe      4
```

Data

```
lab <- list(Q1=c('Yes'='1','NO'='2','Maybe'='3'), Q2=c('All'='1','Some'='2','Rarely'='3'))
df <- structure(list(Q1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Q2 = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks that's great!

Comment: I wasn't aware I could only choose one answer, but your's is deffo preferred. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` statements:

**SAMPLE DATA**:

```
set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(
  Q1 = sample(1:3, 10, replace = T), 
  Q2 = sample(1:4, 10, replace = T), 
  Q3 = sample(1:3, 10, replace = T)
  )
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
df$Q1_new <- ifelse(df$Q1==1, "Yes",
                    ifelse(df$Q1==2, "No", "Maybe"))
df
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1_new
1   2  1  3     No
2   3  1  1  Maybe
3   3  2  3  Maybe
4   3  4  3  Maybe
5   1  3  1    Yes
6   3  4  3  Maybe
7   1  2  1    Yes
8   3  2  1  Maybe
9   2  1  3     No
10  1  4  1    Yes
```

And continue in the same way for `Q2`and `Q3`:

```
df$Q2_new <- ifelse(df$Q2==1, "All the time",
                    ifelse(df$Q2==2, "Some of the time",
                           ifelse(df$Q2==3, "Rarely", "Never")))
df$Q3_new <- ifelse(df$Q3==1, "6 hours",
                    ifelse(df$Q3==2, "7 hours", "8 hours"))
df
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1_new           Q2_new  Q3_new
1   2  1  3     No     All the time 8 hours
2   3  1  1  Maybe     All the time 6 hours
3   3  2  3  Maybe Some of the time 8 hours
4   3  4  3  Maybe            Never 8 hours
5   1  3  1    Yes           Rarely 6 hours
6   3  4  3  Maybe            Never 8 hours
7   1  2  1    Yes Some of the time 6 hours
8   3  2  1  Maybe Some of the time 6 hours
9   2  1  3     No     All the time 8 hours
10  1  4  1    Yes            Never 6 hours
```